# WordPress rewrite rules, custom structure for taxonomies returning 404

Tags: wordpress

I want help in making a custom URL structure for WordPress taxonomies and custom post type... I made the below code but it always returns 404 code there a template file in them directory but it doesn't seems to be the cause of this issue.

So below you will find all of the needed code to debug or point me to the right direction to make this work.

I added this into my functions.php

```
  add_permastruct('product', '/%category%/', array(
        'with_front' => false
    ));
    // Define custom permalink structure for "template-type" taxonomy.
    add_permastruct('part', '/%category%/themes/%part%/', array(
        'with_front' => false
    ));
```

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_themes() {

/**
 * Post Type: Themes.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "Themes", "my-theme" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Theme", "my-theme" ),
    "menu_name" => __( "Themes", "my-theme" ),
    "all_items" => __( "All Themes", "my-theme" ),
    "add_new_item" => __( "Add New Theme", "my-theme" ),
    "edit_item" => __( "Edit Theme", "my-theme" ),
    "new_item" => __( "New Theme", "my-theme" ),
    "view_item" => __( "View Theme", "my-theme" ),
    "view_items" => __( "View Themes", "my-theme" ),
    "search_items" => __( "Search Theme", "my-theme" ),
    "not_found" => __( "No templates found", "my-theme" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Themes", "my-theme" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "delete_with_user" => false,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
    "has_archive" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "/%categories%/themes", "with_front" => false ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "menu_icon" => "/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/templates.webp",
    "supports" => array( "title", "thumbnail" ),
    "taxonomies" => array( "category","part" ),
);

register_post_type( "theme", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_themes' );
```

```
function cptui_register_my_taxes_category() {

/**
 * Taxonomy: Categories.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "Categories", "my-theme" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Category", "my-theme" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Categories", "my-theme" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => false,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => false,
    "show_admin_column" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "category",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
    "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
    );
register_taxonomy( "category", array( "template" ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_category' );
```

```
function cptui_register_my_taxes_template_type() {

/**
 * Taxonomy: Parts.
 */

$labels = array(
    "name" => __( "Parts", "my-theme" ),
    "singular_name" => __( "Part", "my-theme" ),
    "edit_item" => __( "Edit Part", "my-theme" ),
);

$args = array(
    "label" => __( "Parts", "my-theme" ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => false,
    "show_admin_column" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => true,
    "rest_base" => "part",
    "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
    "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
    );
register_taxonomy( "part", array( "template" ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_template_type' );
```

Answer (score 0):

`add_permastruct()` needs to be called e.g. inside the [init hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) (not directly in functions.php) to be effective. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170375/203898) or this [WP Docs comment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_permastruct/#comment-5415) for an example.

Comment: I didn't mention that in the code I posted but I added them into a function and called it using init hook